# Bootstrap DateTime Picker. startDate не корректно работает с месяцами

Tags: bootstrap

В этом плагине есть опция `startDate` с помощью которой устанавливаем дату, раньше которой выбирать день нельзя. Для дней она работает корректно, но если нажать на месяц, два предыдущих месяца для выбора не доступны(на момент написания)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    calendarId = '#dateTimePicker';
    var firstday = new Date();
    var lastday = new Date();
    lastday.setDate(firstday.getDate() + 366);
    $(calendarId).datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: 0,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        startDate: firstday,
        endDate: lastday
    });
</script>
```

[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/d9ahC06ctCnIhf2FSLCK?p=preview)

Это баг плагина или не так настроил?
Модификацию плагина брал с этой странички: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

> startDate Date. Default: Beginning of time
>
> The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be
>   disabled.